# Entity ORM Joining Two Tables Off ID ForeignKey given non-foreignkey?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a string, `name`.

I have two tables:

## Table 1:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |     PadName      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          12         |      "Hello"     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

## Table 2

```
|------------------------------------------|------------------|
|      MetaDataID (FK to ID in table1)     |    ..........    |
|------------------------------------------|------------------|
|                  12                      |    Other Data..
|------------------------------------------|------------------|
```

## Example Query:

Select ID from table1 given a `padName` the join that ID with table2.

I'm using entity framework in C# and what I want is to feed in a `PadName` in *Table 1* and then get all the associated *Table 2* data where the ID fields match (since table2 has an FK relationship to table 1).

I've seen some example code like the following:

```
  var query = _context.PadMetaData
      .Where(x => x.PadName == padName).Select(p => new { p.id });
```

Then I want to take that `id` result and join it with the MetaDataId in table2.

But I can't seem to achieve what I want.

Comment: You need to provide more data, it is not clear enough

Comment: @staa99 I want to select ID from table1 given a `padName` the join that ID with table2.

Comment: @staa99 updated

Comment: `var data = db.Table1.Where(x => x.PadName == padName).Join(db.Table2, x => x.ID, x => x.FK, (a, b) => b).ToList();`